# How to check if second column of a table contains certain text in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, find, contains

I want to use JavaScript to loop through an HTML table to see if a cell in the second column contains a the variable "`orderNum`" (this can only appear once or never in the specific column).

I tried the following but this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

My JS:

```
$(objIE.document).find('#trans_log_table').find("td:eq(1):contains('" + orderNum + "')").length
```

Comment: without HTML its hard to tell where exactly does your error lie. You could shorten your selector to $("#trans_log_table td:eq(1):contains('" + orderNum + "')") Also, i take it that your orderNum are strictly alphanumeric?

Comment: Thanks, yes the orderNum is alphanumeric. I'll try with your modified way.

Comment: Again I'm not sure wheter or not it will fix your problem, if you could post a sample HTML or a link to a JSFiddle it would be a whole lot easier to help you

Comment: Thanks. I know, unfortunately I cannot provide this here. Can you let me know if adding .length to what you provided should return 1 in my case ?

Comment: Yes, testing .length after the $() call being equal to 1 would let you know that you've found an element matching the criteria (that is a <td> that's the second element in a collection of <td> and containing the orderNum you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking a little bit about your case, the problem probably lies in the jQuery selector, because you select all  in your table and then apply the :eq(1), you probably only take the first row second column before applying the contains filter.

Try rewriting your selector as follow

```
$("#trans_log_table tr>td:eq(1):contains('" + orderNum + "')")
```

Comment: Thanks for this ! If I wanted to alert the text of this TD for testing would I just alert the above with .text() ?

Comment: I think the selector is still wrong as this always returns nothing.

Comment: can you open your dev site in chrome, right click inspect element on the td you're trying to get to and in the "Elements" tab of the dev tools right click on the actual node in the tree and copy the results of "Copy CSS Path"?